# Not receiving airflow email-alert from airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

In our airflow there are many components some based on python and some are based on pyspark. as airflow does not support pyspark yet so we are connecting those components from Airflow to EMR . We are receiving mails from EMR but python components from airflow level we are not getting any email-alert.so  is there any method to add config at runtime in Airflow.

Comment: email alert on what? Please post the code of the operator that you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.